# Kendo UI Mobile Listview dataitem undefined on second search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, kendo-ui

I am using a Kendo Mobile Listview to display the contents of a json file. The first search works great, On the click event I am able to view the dataitem bound to that listitem. However after the second search the dataitem becomes undefined. There are a number of ways I can think of to get around this however there is no reason this current method should not be able to work. Is it because the listview should not have it's datasource defined a second time? Any insight is appreciated. Thank you.
HTML

```
<span id="search">
                <input id="inputSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="k-textbox"/>
                <a id="btnSearch" class="k-button" type="submit"><span class="k-icon k-i-search" >...</span></a>
            </span>
```

Please refine your search

Here's the js snippet:

```
 $.ajax({
                       cache:false,
                       type:"GET",
                       dataType: "json",
                       url: "http://"+host+"/Api"+requestController+queryString,
                       headers: {"AuthToken":cookie},
                       success:
                           function (data) {
                               var val = data.data;                                       
                                    if(val.length!=0) {
                                        $("#customerList").data
                                        var customerDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: val });
                                        customerDataSource.read();
                                        $("#customerList").kendoMobileListView({
                                            dataSource: customerDataSource,
                                            template: '<a>${Company}<span class="k-status-text"> <br />${CustNo}</span></a>',
                                            dataType:"json",
                                            style: "inset",
                                            click: function(e){    
//!!!! EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE ON SECOND SEARCH. DATAITEM UNDEFINED                                                
                                                alert(e.dataItem.CustNo);
                                                // redirect to
                                                app.navigate("#overview-customer");

                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        $("#customerList").append('<li>' +'<div class="k-block k-info-colored">'+
                                            'Please refine your search'+'</div>' + '</li>');
                                    }

                           }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-creating the listview each time you search

```
$("#customerList").kendoMobileListView({
```

which is an expesive operation especially for mobile devices. Better initialize (create) the mobile listview once and use the **[dataSource.data()](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#data)** method to change the data it uses. This will also ensure that you wont have problems like the one you experience.

Comment: I agree. I've been messing with that. I will give that method a shot and let you know. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I will update this post with the revised bindings for others to reference once it allows me to unlock.

Answer (score 0):

As per Petur's answer the list view should be bound like so. Instantiating the listview with each click was taxing and incompatible with Kendo's scripts.

```
 var customerDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ });
    // Mobile listview
     $("#customerList").kendoMobileListView({
                                            dataSource: customerDataSource,
                                            template: '<a>${Company}<span class="k-status-text"> <br />${CustNo}</span></a>',
                                            dataType:"json",
                                            style: "inset",
                                            click: function(e){
                                                var index = $(e.item).index();
                                                var text= $(e.item).index();
                                                alert(e.dataItem.CustNo);
                                                // redirect to
                                                app.navigate("#overview-customer");


                                            },
                                            dataBound: function(e){
                                                alert("Ive been bound");
                                            }
                                        });

      $('#search a').click(function () {
          var searchstr = $('#search input').val();
          var requestController = "/Customers";
          var queryString= "?filtercriteria=custno-"+searchstr+"&company-"+searchstr;
                    $.ajax({
                       cache:false,
                       type:"GET",
                       dataType: "json",
                       url: "http://"+host+"/Api"+requestController+queryString,
                       headers: {"AuthToken":cookie},
                       success:
                           function (data) {
                               var val = data.data;
                                    if(val.length!=0) {
                                        var ds = [{ data: val }];
                                        customerDataSource.data(val);

                                    } else {
                                        $("#customerList").append('<li>' +'<div class="k-block k-info-colored">'+
                                            'Please refine your search'+'</div>' + '</li>');
                                    }

                           }
                    });
            });
```